# Cypress testing: How to type text into a Froala editor?

Tags: cypress, froala

I've been struggling with this issue - recently introduced Froala editors to a page on our site, and I'm updating the Cypress tests so that they'll pass.
The problem I'm having is how to 'type' or even set invisibly the text in these editors.

For example, in the browser dev tools console I can run this:

```js
$('#successfullySubmittedTextArea')[0]['data-froala.editor'].html.insert('new text!');
```

How do I translate this over to my Cypress test?
I've tried:

```js
Cypress.$('#successfullySubmittedTextArea')[0]['data-froala.editor'].html.insert('new text!');
```

which doesn't error, but doesn't work.
Please help, sure I'm missing something fundamental and obvious!

Answer (score 2):

To translate this to Cypress commands

```js
$('#successfullySubmittedTextArea')[0]['data-froala.editor'].html.insert('new text!')
```

you want

```js
cy.get('#successfullySubmittedTextArea')
  .eq(0)
  .its('data-froala.editor')
  .type('new text!')
```

because `['data-froala.editor']` references the elements property named `data-froala.editor`.

This is probably not the best Cypress command sequence. Ideally, look at the HTML to decide the best strategy, for example (Froala v4)

```js
cy.get('.fr-wrapper')
  .eq(0)
  .find('.fr-element') 
  .then($el => {
    $el.innerHTML = 'new text!'  // better than `.type()` because you can add formatting
  })
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get your solution to work (the final part where the innerHTML is set). I'm not sure if it's something particular with my setup and app, but you set me off on the right track - so thank you!
Out of interest for future visitors to this question I ended up creating a command like this:

Cypress.Commands.add("setFroalaText", (textareaIdSelector, text) => {
    return cy.get(textareaIdSelector)
    .prev()
    .find('.fr-wrapper')
    .find('.fr-element > p')
    .invoke('prop', 'innerHTML', text);
  }
);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no iframe, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#successfullySubmittedTextArea')
  .eq(0)
  .find('data-froala.editor')
  .clear()
  .type('new text!')
```